# ADO.NET SqlCommand: Cannot insert the value NULL into column

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlcommand

```
sCnd =  "INSERT INTO .dbo.Table(Col1, Col2, Col3) Values (1,2,3);

using (DbCommand tempCommand2 = CommandFactory.CreateCommand(db))
{
    tempCommand2.CommandText = sCmd;
    tempCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Table has also a Col4 that does not allow null.

**Error:** Cannot insert the value NULL into column Col4

When I execute the sCmd in the Management Studio everything works fine.

Why do I get the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify a value for a column `NULL` is taken, unless there is a `constraint` which says otherwise.

As `Col4` doesn't allow `NULL` and looks like it doesn't have a `default` value `constraint` that is why you get the error.

You haven't shown the SQL you are executing in SSMS, but I'd guess, different database (production/development), different table?

Comment: You haven't shown the SQL you are executing in SSMS, but I'd guess, different database (production/development), different table?  Yes ... :s

Answer (score 2):

> Table has also a Col4 that does not allow null.

There is your answer. If Management Studio works anyway, it is probably inserting a default value?

Answer (score 2):

You get the exception because you are not inserting a value for the `Col4` column, which does not allow `nulls` and, I can only assume, does not have a default value.

But it seems like you've asked the wrong question; don't you mean to be asking, why does the query run in SSMS?

I suspect the answer to *that* question would be buried somewhere in the actual syntax, which you have elected not to include.